# VBA Error 'Subscript out of Range'

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a copy of a large macro enabled (xlsm) file in xlsx format.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\original.xlsm")

    Dim mySheetList() As String
    ReDim mySheetList(0 To (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) - 1)
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        mySheetList(a) = ws.Name
        a = a + 1
    Next ws

    'actually save
    Worksheets(mySheetList).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="ORIGINAL_COPY.xlsx" 'default ext
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

I am getting subscript out of range error at following line:

```
mySheetList(a) = ws.Name
```

Comment: Include `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` in the SaveAs command

Answer (score 0):

You are sizing the array with ThisWorkbook.Sheets but the loop use ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets. You need the same reference to avoid issues when multiple workbooks are opened.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 4 different references to workbooks:

`wb`, `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` are not necessarily the same thing. Furthermore, when you use `Worksheets` without prefixing it with a workbook reference, you're implicitly referencing the Activeworkbook. And, when you use Worksheets.Copy without any arguments, you're implictly creating a new workbook.

Currently, if `ThisWorkbook` has *fewer* sheets than original.xlsm, then your array will not be large enough to accommodate indexes larger than the count of sheets in ThisWorkbook. That is what is causing your out of bounds error.

I've adjusted the code. This will open the XLSM, copy the sheets, save the new XLSX workbook, and close the original XLSM, leaving the new XLSX workbook open.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim wbOriginal As Workbook
    Dim wbOutput As Workbook

    Set wbOriginal = Workbooks.Open("C:\original.xlsm")

    Dim mySheetList() As String
    ReDim mySheetList(0 To (wbOriginal.Sheets.Count) - 1)
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 0

    For Each ws In wbOriginal.Worksheets
        mySheetList(a) = ws.Name
        a = a + 1
    Next ws

    'Unfortunately, Worksheets.Copy isn't a function, so it doesn't
    'return the workbook that it creates, so we have to execute the
    'copy, then find the activeworkbook
    Worksheets(mySheetList).Copy

    Set wbOutput = ActiveWorkbook
    'actually save
    wbOutput.SaveAs Filename:="ORIGINAL_COPY.xlsx" 'default ext
    wbOriginal.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with all that looping?

```
Sub MM()

    Dim sourceWB As Excel.Workbook

    Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Original.xlsm")
    sourceWB.SaveAs "C:\ORIGINAL_COPY.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkook
    sourceWB.Close False '// Optional

End Sub
```

The `.SaveAs()` method would be far more effective.

---

As mentioned in other answers, your issue seems to be with `wb`, `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` being used interchangeably when they are actually different things.

- `wb` is a workbook object that has been set to "C:\original.xlsm". It will always refer to that workbook unless you close the workbook, empty the object, or assign a new object to it.
- `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the workbook that is currently **active** in Excel's forefront window. *(i.e. The workbook you can see on your screen)*
- `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook in which the currently executing code belongs to. To quickly explain the difference:

Workbook A is the only workbook open, and has some code in to open another workbook (let's call it Workbook B).

At the moment, Workbook A is the `ActiveWorkbook`.

The code in workbook A starts running, workbook A is now the `ActiveWorkbook` **and** `ThisWorkbook` (because the running codes resides in ***this workbook***)

The code opens Workbook B, which naturally opens in the forefront of Excel. Now Workbook B is the `ActiveWorkbook` and Workbook A is still the `ThisWorkbook`

---

Hopefully that clears it up a bit for you...